# Add Relational Query Data to main JSON result

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, parse-platform

in my Angular app I'm trying to display a set of results that come from three Classes. Data is stored on Parse.com.

I can do just fine with the Pointer relation type for one-to-one (associated scores are being returned).

Problem starts when I try to include data from the Location class into my final returned JSON.

Hopefully this is just a basic notation thing I'm missing.
Thanks a lot!

## Doctors

- String: firstname
- Pointer: score
- Relation: location

## Scores

- Number: scoreOne
- Number: scoreTwo

## Locations

- String: name
- String: address

  ```
    .controller('BrowseCtrl', function($scope) {

          // Get "Doctors" and associated "Scores"
          // via Pointer in Doctors Class named "score"
          var query = new Parse.Query("Doctors");
          query.include("score");
          query.find()
          .then(function(result){

            var doctorsArray = new Array();

            for(i in result){

              var obj = result[i];

              var doctorIds = obj.id;
              var docFirstname = obj.get("firstname");          
              var mainScore = obj.get("score").get("mainScore");

              doctorsArray.push({
                Scores:{
                  DocMainScore: mainScore
                },
                firstname: docFirstname,
              });


            }

            // Get Locations.
            // -can be more than one per Doctor
            // Class Doctors has a Relation column "location" pointing to Locations
            var locationsArray = new Array();
            var locationRelation = obj.relation('location');
            var locationQuery = locationRelation.query();

            locationQuery.find({
              success: function(locations) {
                for(j in locations){
                 var locObj = locations[j];
                 var locName = locObj.get("name"); 
                 console.log(locName);
               }
             }
           })

            // send data to the view
            $scope.myData = doctorsArray;
            console.log(doctorsArray);
          });
        })
  ```

What I am trying to do is get the data from Locations into the doctorsArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using obj outside the for where it's assigned. This way it'll only get location for the last doc, I'm pretty sure it's not what you wanted.

What you want must be something like this:

```
// inside your Doctors query result

Parse.Promise.when(

  // get locations for all doctors
  result.map(function(doc) {
    return doc.relation('location').query().find();
  })

).then(function() {
  var docsLocations = arguments;

  // then map each doctor
  $scope.myData = result.map(function(doc, i) {
    // and return an object with all properties you want
    return {
      Scores: {
        DocMainScore: doc.get('score').get('mainScore')
      },
      firstname: doc.get('firstname'),
      locations: docsLocations[i]
    };
  });

});
```

Comment: This works in adding data to the same JSON but the problem is that it is only returning an address object for the first Doctor object only. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, I think you edited the code and I used a slightly previous version. Let me adjust to your edit.

Comment: Same problem: only the first doctor has a locations.Object attached.

Others have: locations: undefined

Comment: Sorry, I think it's fixed now, please let me know if you managed to make it work

Comment: Thanks a lot Pacheco, no need for sorry, your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I will make another question on adding data from another relational class that I created (say Doctor Reviews) with a 'reviews' Relational column.

Comment: Here is the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31124591/get-data-from-multiple-relational-tables

Comment: Sorry dude, but StackOverflow isn't a free code website. It's a question and answer website for generic topics that can be helpful to someone else. Don't use it because you're too lazy to think, your new question is pretty much the same as this one

Comment: What would be the difference? if you don't mind hinting. Thanks